# Is SQLiteConnection.Update() safe from SQL Injection?

Tags: c#, sqlite

As title.

Assume I have the following class:

```
public class Property
{

    [PrimaryKey]
    public int PropertyID { get; set; }      
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Address3 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }

    public Property()
    {

    }

    private void SaveData()
    {
        SQLiteConnection dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), "mypath");
        dbConn.Update(this)
    }
}
```

Initially when pulled from the DB all the fields are filled out, presented to the user in textboxes and are editable. If i call `SaveData()` are the inputs safe to use "as is"?

Normally I would parameterise each of the user inputs for obvious reasons, but if `Update()` does this automatically then it would obviously be pointless. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Yes it is. Documentation have no mention of SQL Injection and thus it's presumed to be safe

Comment: @HameedSyed fiddler won't do anything because this isnt a web based application..